# How to display Pending Changes as list rather than tree view in VS2012?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

The TFS Pending Changes has moved from its own window to a tab in the Team Explorer.

The pending changes are now displayed as a treeview that reflects the structure of the solution.

How can I display the pending changes as a flat list/grid that can be sorted by various columns?

Comment: FYI, the product does not have an official name yet. When it does, it will not be "Visual Studio 2011" (a past year). The "11" in "Visual Studio 11" refers to the version number (Visual Studio 2010 was version 10; VS2008 was version 9).

Comment: My answer was deleted for some reason, see here for previously posted solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13626589/295813

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After experimentation, I've found it's a link on that page, `Show all included changes`:

[image]

Comment: This option only seems to appear upon many pending changes.

Comment: This option seems to be missing from the RTM release

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, it says "Included Changes (152 of 347)", the link is only available if you have more than about 150 changes. Even then, the original list in VS2010 is more convenient to use in my opinion.

Comment: One can vote for getting the list back here in VS uservoice forum http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2961145-switch-between-list-view-and-tree-view-in-pending-

Comment: Here is the link to vote, which has more momentum.  Better to case your votes here instead:  http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2654486-vs11-bring-back-the-old-pending-changes-window

Comment: I still prefer the old Pending Changes window from VS2010, and was going to just go ahead and write my own. Well, looking at the comments from the voting link in the comment above, somebody already has done just that: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/79e9baa7-ea8b-4335-86ba-ae929bf67222

Answer (score 9):

It's possible to add "TF.exe Checkin" as an external tool, see  [answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14234794/52277).
However it pop-ups after some delay, which is annoying.

I found that if you have only a few recently checked-out files that you want to check-in together, using pending changes tree view is quicker. However if you need to check-in some of many check-out files, "TF.exe Checkin" list is more convenient.

Alternatively try [TeamPilgrim Free VS extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/79e9baa7-ea8b-4335-86ba-ae929bf67222) -
a replacement for Visual Studio 2012's Team Explorer inspired by the Visual Studio 2010's Team Explorer by Stanley Goldman

Answer (score 5):

@G_P added this as a comment to a different answer, but I think it deserves an answer slot of its own.

The **TeamPilgrim** extension includes a replacement pending changes window/tab.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/79e9baa7-ea8b-4335-86ba-ae929bf67222

Comment: (I've marked this answer as Community Wiki so that I don't benefit from what is effectively someone else's answer).

Answer (score 2):

There is a "pending changes" filter on the Visual Studio 2012 Solution explorer.  It will display all your files that are checked out the same as the Team Explorer, but without all the extra garbage about Notes or Work Items.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/08/14/showing-files-with-pending-changes-or-files-that-are-open-in-visual-studio-2012-solution-explorer.aspx