# Hide TF.exe command prompt window when use old pending changes in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204845/vs2012-return-to-a-normal-tfs-checkin-window/14234794#14234794%29) as a solution for old pending changes window in VS 2012.

Does exists an argument which doesn't display the command prompt window but displays pending changes window only ?

---

I created a VS 2012 extension, and I wrote the following code:

```
public void Exec( string commandName, vsCommandExecOption executeOption, ref object varIn, ref object varOut, ref bool handled )
      {
         handled = false;
         if ( executeOption == vsCommandExecOption.vsCommandExecOptionDoDefault ) {
            if ( commandName == "OldPendingChanges.Connect.OldPendingChanges" ) {
               handled = true;

               using ( var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process { StartInfo = CProcessStartInfo() } ) {
                  process.Start();
                  //process.WaitForExit();
               }

               return;
            }
         }
      }

      private ProcessStartInfo CProcessStartInfo()
      {
         return new ProcessStartInfo
         {
            FileName = "tf.exe",
            RedirectStandardInput = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE",
            Arguments = "checkin"
         };
      }
```

but it still appears that command prompt window. I used also `WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` but no success.

Thanks

Comment: I tried a trick but no success. Please see my updated post.