# "tf status" to see pending changes without "detected" adds

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

I want to use `TF.EXE` to get a list of the pending changes in my source branch. I want the *same list* I see in Visual Studio's "Pending Changes" window.

For instance, I current have 167 pending changes shown in the Pending Changes window, about 50/50 edits and adds.  Under Excluded Changes, there is a button titled "Detected: 49998 add(s)". These are literally tens of thousands of intermediate/output files in my solution directory that are *not* under source control, which I don't *want* under source control, and which are not "Pending Change" by any definition of that term.

However, when I do `tf status` in my solution directory, it shows me all these files as adds. How do I get just the list of Pending Changes shown in Visual Studio (i.e the files that will actually be checked-in when I submit changes)?

Alternatively, some way to copy the list from the Visual Studio UI. I just want to put this list in an email, but the UI is horrible (won't expand to use available vertical space, can't copy text, etc.) and the command line gives me garbage.

(EDIT) Solution: `tf checkin /recursive`, select items in list and hit CTRL+C to get list on clipboard.

Comment: That was a temporarily scary ("What if no window appears and everything goes ahead and checks in `/noprompt` style?!!") but ultimately very useful trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the check in window such as this question: [VS2012 return to a normal TFS checkin window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204845/vs2012-return-to-a-normal-tfs-checkin-window)

You could use [tf check in command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/checkin-command) with the prompt window, should be able to copy the list in the E-Mail then. Another method is using TFS api to do this.

Comment: I used `tf checkin /recursive` to get the old-school popup window. This window can be stretched full screen and actually uses that space, so I could get a proper screenshot. Even better, the text is copyable. There's no indication in the UI, but if you select all the pending items and hit CTRL+C, the text shows up on the clipboard. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some years later but might still be useful for someone:

```
tf status -nodetect
```