# Is there a way to use the Visual Studio 2010-style Pending Changes / Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

The Team Explorer / Pending Changes in VS 2012 is horrible.

Is there a way to bring back the VS 2010 Pending Changes window?

Even a good standalone TFS client will do.

Comment: Follow-up: After a few months of working with VS 2012, I actually prefer the new Pending Changes, although sometimes it can be a pain in the ass when you're searching for a specific file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a new external tool (tools -> external tools)

**Command:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe

**Argument:** checkin

**Initial Directory:** $(SolutionDir)

**Use Output Window** Unticked (dialog doesn't seem to popup if this is on)

Comment: Is this how to check in from the command line? This is not what I asked about.

Comment: This will add a new menu item in your tools menu which pops up the old checkin dialog.

Comment: See similar answer with screenshot http://stackoverflow.com/a/14234794/52277

Comment: Keeping the Output Window unticked still shows the dialog in VS2012.

Comment: Wanna try answering this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382353/using-a-docked-old-style-pending-changes-window-with-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 12):

There is a free 3rd party plugin called TeamPilgrim which imitates the old pending changes window from Visual Studio 2010.

[image]

It is apparently still in development but is a reasonable solution until Microsoft (hopefully) resolve the UserVoice request.

Download and further details here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/79e9baa7-ea8b-4335-86ba-ae929bf67222

Comment: Wanna try answering this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382353/using-a-docked-old-style-pending-changes-window-with-visual-studio-2013

Comment: @YonatanNir __TeamPilgrim__ is not developed anymore. and currently works with VS12 only. I've made some changes to make it work in VS13, but it is not yet completed. you are can download alpha version [here](http://devfilescloud.com/download/327), or see source [here](https://github.com/itsho/TeamPilgrim)

Comment: @itsho could you please write it also as an answer to the question I gave a link to. It might help many people who comes across that question.

Answer (score 4):

There is a "pending changes" filter on the Visual Studio 2012 Solution explorer.  While I'd rather have a separate window, this is much better than adding a separate command.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/08/14/showing-files-with-pending-changes-or-files-that-are-open-in-visual-studio-2012-solution-explorer.aspx

Comment: Wanna try answering this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382353/using-a-docked-old-style-pending-changes-window-with-visual-studio-2013