# Dealing with VS/TFS 2012 UI

Tags: explorer

Ok - so 2012 has been around for a bit and it came for our company to upgrade. But I cant say that I have been a fan of the new UI changes even since the early beta & RC versions.

I think it's dumbed down from 2010 and the old layout and placement of UI elements was just a more efficient UI/UX design IMO.

Specifically I am annoyed by the new Team Explorer.

Is there any way to get TFS2010-style team explorer in 2012?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use the Visual Studio 2010-style Pending Changes / Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493352/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-visual-studio-2010-style-pending-changes-team-explor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't, unless there is an obscure plugin that someone's released to replace it.

As someone who has been using it since some of the earliest public betas, I can say that you will get used to it fairly quickly - personally I wish there was a tab for each of work items, builds, etc. Get familiar with you Home button, and consider keeping it on a second monitor if you need more room.

Comment: I looked as well, the closest I found was an icon replacement pack for those monochrome blobs MS expects us to stare at.. if anyone's interested ill post a link.