# Using a docked old style Pending Changes window with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, menu, tfs, visual-studio-2013

This is a follow up question for this question:

[VS2012 return to a normal TFS checkin window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204845/vs2012-return-to-a-normal-tfs-checkin-window)

I've used the solution of creating a new command which was added to the Tools menu, but using this option opens the Pending Changes window as a new process which is closed when I'm done using it. Is there a way to leave it open permanently like you could in 2010 (where it was simply docked at the bottom of the screen near the Output, Errors etc.) ?

Comment: Wanna check https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2654486-vs11-bring-back-the-old-pending-changes-window

Comment: I believe this link is the announcement of the NEW pending changes window with the ability to dock it rather than just view it in the team server window. However, I want the old one docked, the same one as is opened with your solution from the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

All `External tools` run as separate process.
for process that use command line you can tick "Use output window", but since `tf.exe checkin` actually opens another window - you won't be able to dock it into Visual Studio as far as I know.

You may consider using [TeamPilgrim for VS2013](https://github.com/itsho/TeamPilgrim) which I've forked from [TeamPilgrim for VS2012](https://github.com/StanleyGoldman/TeamPilgrim).

Notice:

1. I forked it since original author (*Stanley Goldman*) have stopped the development.
2. It's still in alpha state.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "pending changes" filter on the Visual Studio 2012 Solution explorer. While I'd rather have a separate window, this is much better than adding a separate command.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/08/14/showing-files-with-pending-changes-or-files-that-are-open-in-visual-studio-2012-solution-explorer.aspx

(From [Is there a way to use the Visual Studio 2010-style Pending Changes / Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493352/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-visual-studio-2010-style-pending-changes-team-explor/16068451#comment41957013_16068451))